# How to take notice of filenames in different locale in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, character-encoding, printwriter

My application is sifting through a M3U playlist and generating a Windows batch file (copy_files.bat) using the following command:

```
printWriter = new PrintWriter("copy_files.bat", "UTF-8");
```

It generates the appropriate batch file that mostly works, but fails to copy some files that have foreign characters in their filenames. The same behavior occurs when using Java's built in function for copying files (few files cannot be found on the system due to filename character encoding). Please advise!

Comment: Do you use Java 7? If yes, do you use `Path`?

Comment: how do the names of the files look like, both in the BAT and in the command line? try: `type copy_files.bat`, `dir /b` and `chcp` in the same command prompt, and post the results.

Comment: type gives me mostly a good list of files (contents of the batch file), with some files that contain unreadable characters (∩┐╜). the same output comes by type-ing the M3U file, so the batch file contains authentic copy of the M3U file. (you know how these files are unusable except on the computer where they were made, so I am converting them) and chcp is Active code page: 437

Comment: PATH? Path is not needed here in any way... I made a good converted for M3U files, but some filenames contain unrecognizable letters... Was Java 7, now Java 8 since yesterday :-)

Comment: I think that I am wrong... The copying of strings from M3U file to batch file FAILS somehow. By using Notepad++ I can see that M3U file has nice looking filenames, but the batch file does not look good in some places.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap it up, I cannot import some playlists that are M3U, but M3U8 playlist contains the data that can be used. Here's a small project to test this.
http://m3uexporttool.sourceforge.net/